# Angular:Trying to do ngSwitch with Conditions

Tags: angular, ng-switch

I'm interested in doing ngswitch in case and
The number is greater than 5
So give 50 px to its font size

The number is less than 2 so give it 15 px....

I could not find a suitable syntax so there is no code here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngSwitch` is not the best way to do this, since the `ngSwitch` expression expects a match in the `ngSwitchCase`.

example from the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch):

```
<container-element [ngSwitch]="switch_expression">
  <!-- the same view can be shown in more than one case -->
  <some-element *ngSwitchCase="match_expression_1">...</some-element>
  <some-element *ngSwitchCase="match_expression_2">...</some-element>
  <some-other-element *ngSwitchCase="match_expression_3">...</some-other-element>
  <!--default case when there are no matches -->
  <some-element *ngSwitchDefault>...</some-element>
</container-element>
```

So in your case, you are trying to pass a *condition* to `match_expression` when the directive expects a *value*. You could pass a simple condition (e.g. number > 5 or number < 2) in the `switch_expression`, but since you have more than one condition this will not work.

You should go about it a different way, easiest would be with `ngIf`.
If you only want to apply styling conditionally you could also use `ngStyle` or `ngClass`

Comment: Bounchlis I did it **[ngStyle]="{'font-size.px':Tub.scoops > 5 ? 30 : 15}"** But it's not good for me because I want to make some conditions

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for ngStyle (conditional styling). You can use it like this:

```
  [ngStyle]="{
    'font-size':
      condition
        ? onTrue
        : onFalse
  }"
```

Comment: I tried to do this before the ngswitch but encountered a problem
Because I'm interested in setting a size according to the condition
But I have to also give the opposite size which is not good for me

I want to check if it is larger than a certain number so give it a specific size without else
In addition I have to set 3 such that it seems to me possible only 1

Comment: If you don´t want else statement you can try this trick: condition && onTrue

Comment: like this: **[ngStyle]="{'font-size.px':Tub.scoops > 5 && 30}"** If I want to do some of these is it possible?

Comment: Not sure about your syntax. I would write it like this: [ngStyle]="{'font-size': Tub.scoops > 5 && '30px'}"

Comment: syntax errorrrr

Comment: Had a quotes typo, now edited. And confirmed on my project.

Comment: Okay, if I want to add 2 more conditions is this legal?

Comment: Testing limits of physics? Haven´t tested that. But I don´t see why it shouldn´t work. You may have to use parenthesis: [ngStyle]="{'font-size': (condition1 || condition2) && '30px'}"

Comment: That's not what I meant,
I want different conditions and set different size,
I tried but it overwhelms me first

Comment: I believe you mean conditional chains. Just tested, seems to work fine. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/FrzJck/zxb47ajc/)